# Need examples for numpy basic indexing with `non-ndarray sequence`

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

In numpy doc about [basic slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing), there is a situation described as:

> basic slicing is also initiated if the selection object is any non-ndarray sequence (such as a list) containing slice objects, the Ellipsis object, or the newaxis object, but not for integer arrays or other embedded sequences.

It's hard to get the idea of this description. When does this situation happen? Can you show me some examples  for this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting convenience.  Lets say that I have the following array:

```
arr = np.arange(100)
```

If I'm being silly, I can slice an array like this:

```
arr[:30, ..., np.newaxis]
```

(The `Ellipsis` doesn't do anything helpful here, but I *can* put it on there).  Basically this tells basic slicing to take the first 30 elements and then add a new axis.

If I'd rather (or if it's more convenient for whatever reason), I can accomplish the same slicing like this:

```
arr[[slice(0, 30), Ellpisis, np.newaxis]]
```

If I have a 2d array:

```
arr = arr.reshape((10, 10))
```

I can have multiple slice objects:

```
arr[[slice(0, 5), slice(5, 10, 2)]]
```

So I suppose that in general, you can think of `arr[[x_0, x_1, x_2, ..., x_N]]` as equivalent to `arr[x_0, x_1, x_2, ..., x_N]` so long as `x_0`, ... `x_N` are all slices, ellipsis, or None.

Comment: You'd usually want to use a tuple here, because if the list doesn't contain a slice, `Ellipsis`, or `np.newaxis`, suddenly you get advanced indexing instead of basic indexing. As stated just above the part the questioner quoted, this behavior for non-tuples is there for backward compatibility.

Comment: @user2357112 -- Yeah, that's a fair point -- though I think that the list version can be useful (e.g. if you're building your indexing object dynamically for each dimension of an array -- particularly if you don't _know_ the dimensions of the array up front)

Comment: `apply_along_axis` makes a `i = np.zeros(nd, 'O')` array, fills it and then uses it via `outarr[tuple(i.tolist())] = res`.